# Recover a link from a site automatically on python

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

in order to lighten my program and make it easy to use, I created an exe that centralizes all functions including the download of various applications and their installation. But the problem I face is that the link is dynamic (the link of the download page is fixed but not the download link). So how to get the second link on the page from the fixed link ?

For example, this link "https://anonfiles.com/D031ebu3uf/untitled.95_png" is fixed and I want to automate the recovery of the non-fixed link store in

```html
<a target="_blank" type="button" id="download-url" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="https://cdn-31.anonfiles.com/D031ebu3uf/91f535ad-1619920351/untitled.95.png"> Download (365 KB)a></a>
```

Code:

```
url = 'https://anonfiles.com/D031ebu3uf/untitled.95_png' 
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True) 
open('page.html', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: Please include your current coding attempt and explain what isn't working.

Comment: To download the page I do 

```url = 'https://anonfiles.com/D031ebu3uf/untitled.95_png'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('page.html', 'wb').write(r.content)```

And after I don't know how to recover the link from this page

Answer (score 0):

Use bS4 and requests. Download and parse the html. Use the id of the element to target it, then extract the href attribute:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://anonfiles.com/D031ebu3uf/untitled.95_png')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
link = soup.select_one('#download-url')['href']
print(link)
```